# Datagrid Remove duplicate rows while Adding

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, datagrid

Hi I want to add a value to datagrid when I input videoNo. to text box and click OK this will show :

[image: Enter a VideoNo]

This is the output

[image: Output when Click OK]

Then when I add the same video again it will duplicate in the datagrid like these:
[image]

How Can I avoid this duplication ?
This is my code for adding

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Visible = false;
        if (txt_vidNo.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Input Video Number", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }
        else
        {
            DialogResult dt = MessageBox.Show("Add Video?", "Continue", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

            if (dt == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                panel4.Visible = true;
                con = koneksyon.getConnect();
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Stock where videoNo ='" + txt_vidNo.Text + "'", con);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr[0], dr[1], dr[2], dr[3], dr[4], dr[5], dr[6], dr[7], dr[8]);
                }
                txt_vidNo.Clear();
                btn_Rent.Visible = true;
                panelPay.Visible = true;
                cmd.Dispose();
                con.Close();
                dr.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                txt_vidNo.Clear();
            }

        }
    }
```

What I want is when I input the same value it will not duplicate in Datagrid, How Can I do these?

Comment: Do you have duplicate entries of a video in your database as well? Is any of the values in your Datarow Unique for a record?

Comment: @BojanB - nope sir, My CatalogNo. is unique cause I set it into PrimaryKey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to check if the value of your unique key is already in the datagrid.

You can do that with LINQ where you check all rows with non null values if the value in Column Catalog Number matches the read Catalog number.

```
while (dr.Read())
{
   if (dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(row => row.Cells[0].Value != null).All(row => (int) row.Cells[0].Value != dr[0]))
      dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr[0], dr[1], dr[2], dr[3], dr[4], dr[5], dr[6], dr[7], dr[8]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change while(dr.Read()) to if(dr.Read())

```
while (dr.Read())
{
  dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr[0], dr[1], dr[2], dr[3], dr[4], dr[5], dr[6], dr[7], dr[8]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand from comments, you just want to guard against duplicate rows, in your case `DB` is not having duplicates, it is user search which returns same records, so you have two options.

1. Don't query for those video numbers if it is fetched and available in the grid.
2. Are as shown in the below example you can guard for duplicates.

.

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    if(!dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Any(x=>x.Cells[0].Value == dr.GetInt32(0)))  // or "GetString(0)" if it istring
    {
         dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr[0], dr[1], dr[2], dr[3], dr[4], dr[5], dr[6], dr[7], dr[8]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops.. it was typo. It should be `x=>x.Cells[0].Value == dr.GetInt32(0)`.

Comment: It is a `Linq` statement, if you are not familiar with `Linq`  replace with `foreach` loop.